# Regular expression to replace in TextPad

Tags: regex, find-and-replace, textpad

I need to replace this:

```
HSOD,BASE,DFLT,001,06-19-2012,[any string],1,0,0
```

With this:

```
HSOD,BASE,DFLT,001,06-19-2012,[any string],1,0,N
```

where the `[any string]` part needs to be a wild card.

Comment: What exactly `[any string]` contains? And what about last zero at right side, it should replace with letter `N`?

Comment: any string contains values like 000NIS00000069 ; and yes replace right side 0 with an N

Answer (score 2):

If all the lines are the same format you can just check for lines ending in ,0 and replace that ,0 with ,N.

Search:

```
,0$
```

Replace:

```
,N
```

If you don't know the value of the last digit(s) then you could do the following.

Search:

```
,[[:digit:]]*$
```

Replace:

```
,N
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find this:

```
(HSOD,BASE,DFLT,001,06-19-2012,.*?,1,0,)0
```

And replace by this:

```
\1N
```

With the regular expression box checked, of course.